# What algorithm is used by stackoverflow's duplicate finder?

Tags: algorithm

When you submit a question here, you are asked to checked if your question is a duplicate. A list of the possible duplicates is displayed to you. How do you think SO evaluates the matching?

Comment: Rather than having people guess, just ask in [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). You may want to write it correctly for best reception.

Comment: I would wager its String Comparison (Edit Distance) and the use of Keywords being present.

Comment: Ok that seems in line with some results I observe: the algorithm does'nt "understand" the topic, it evaluates strings. For the record, I have found this other discussion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270049/what-is-the-algorithm-metric-used-to-determine-question-similarity